# How to set boot partition using BIOS interrupts

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, bios

Windows allows you to set a specific disk partition to boot from. Setting the boot partition allows me to run a custom bootloader that I made the next time the computer is turned on. However, I can't actually do this until I can set the boot partition back to Window's boot partition from my bootloader. What is BIOS interrupt (or other method) that allows me to set the boot partition from my bootloader (real mode x86 program)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no BIOS interrupt to do that.  What you want to do is to set the *active partition flag* for the partition that is supposed to boot.  This flag is stored in the first byte of every partition table entry.  If the byte is 80h, the partition is active, if it is 00h, the partition is not active.  Note that at most one partition should be active.  Here is what you need to do:

- Load the MBR from disk or assume it is at 0000:0600, which is where the MBR normally relocates itself.
- Inspect the bytes at offset 01beh, 01ceh, 01deh, and 01eeh to see which partition is active
- Set all of these bytes to 00h except at most one
- Write the MBR back to disk.  Since the MBR is always the first sector of the disk, you can safely use [Int 13h/AH=03h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0608.htm) to make your code simpler.